# Make changes to API fetch onClick in React

Tags: json, reactjs, rest

I'm prototyping a UI and fetching data from an API like this in React:

```
  componentWillUpdate() {
    fetch(this.state.api + this.state.query  +".json" + this.state.key)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Oops')
        }
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data.results, isLoading: false}))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }))
  }
```

There's a list of other possible categories that I'd like to give users access to. Given a link like this:

```
<li data-facet="arts" onClick={this.handleCategory}>Arts</li>
```

and a handler method like this:

```
handleCategory(event) {
    this.setState({
      query: event.target.getAttribute('data-facet')
    })
  }
```

how do I get the UI to update and show data from the new category? I've been banging my head against this for a couple of days now. I've written several ways to update the fetch string successfully, but none are forcing the component to re-render and show new items. Thanks.

---

Updating with complete component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Moment from 'moment'
import MaterialIcon from 'material-icons-react'
import '../assets/styles/app.scss'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoading: false,
      isMenuOpen: false,
      results: [],
      api: "the//api//here",
      query: "",
      key: "?api-key=XXXXXX"
    };

    this.handleMenu = this.handleMenu.bind(this)
    this.handleCategory = this.handleCategory.bind(this)
  }

  handleMenu() {
    this.setState({
      isMenuOpen: !state.isMenuOpen
    })
  }

  handleCategory(event) {
    this.setState({
      query: event.target.getAttribute('data-facet')
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.state.api + this.state.query  +".json" + this.state.key)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Oops')
        }
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data.results, isLoading: false}))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }))
  }

  render() {
    const { results, isLoading, error } = this.state

    if (error) {
      return <div className="cards">{error.message}</div>
    }

    if (isLoading) {
      return <div className="cards">Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">

        <div className="menu-trigger"><MaterialIcon icon="menu"/></div>
        <div className="menu">
          <ul>
            <li data-facet="arts" onClick={this.handleCategory}>Arts</li>
            <li data-facet="automobiles" onClick={this.handleCategory}>Automobiles</li>
            <li data-facet="books" onClick={this.handleCategory}>Books</li>
            <li data-facet="business" onClick={this.handleCategory}>Business</li>
            <li data-facet="fashion" onClick={this.handleCategory}>Fashion</li>
            <li data-facet="food" onClick={this.handleCategory}>Food</li>
            <li data-facet="health" onClick={this.handleCategory}>Health</li>
            <li data-facet="home" onClick={this.handleCategory}>Home</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="cards">
          {results.slice(0, 10).map(result => (
            <div className="cards__card" key={result.title}>
              <a href={result.url} target="_blank"><h5>{result.title}</h5></a>
              <p>{result.abstract}</p>
              <p className="small">Published {Moment(result.published_date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a')}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App
```

Comment: can you tell me why are you calling api in componentWillUpdate instead of componentDidMount ? also share complete code so that i could check.

Comment: I've updated the question include the full code. I had the fetch in ```componentWillUpdate()``` just because I was messing around. It had been in ```componentDidMount ``` and was working.

Comment: your performance won't be good as you are using multiple same click function in li tag. i think you should loop that and handle through id/value.

Comment: can you share in sandbox so that i could improve.

Comment: Gladly! How would I do that? You mean make a Codepen or something?

Comment: if you don't mind can you tell me your complete api so that i could check

Comment: Sorry, it's a private API. If you have some information about how to generically do what I need I'd appreciate it, but I can't share the API unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your component to re-render with the updated data you need to update the state variable.

Assuming you're storing your data in `this.state.results` - However, you're not updating this state in `handleCategory`.

There are a few things you can do:

- abstract your fetch call so it's reusable
- use arrow functions to get rid of binds in constructor
- get rid of `componentWillUpdate` lifecycle as it's redundant

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      results: [],
      error: null,
    };
  }

  fetchData = (url, query, key) => {
    fetch(`the/api/${url}${query}.json?api-key${key}`)
      .then(res => res.ok && res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data.results, isLoading: false }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchData('api_url', 'all', 'key_here');
  }

  handleCategory = (e) => {
    const cat = e.target.getAttribute('data-facet');
    fetchData('api_url', cat, 'key_here');
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, results, error } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <div className="loading-icon"></div>
    }

    if (error) {
      return <div className="error"></div>    
    }

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <button data-facet="arts" onClick={this.handleCategory}>Arts</button>
        {results.map(res => ...)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. To clarify, in the ```componentDidMount``` phase, should I be hardcoding the api_url, cat, and key as defaults for the first load?

Comment: Sure. You can fallback to defaults so in `cDM` you don't have to call with params. 

ES6 has default params so you can just do `fetchData = (url = 'foo', query = 'all', key = '0') => ...`